# Laravel RESTful best practices

Tags: php, image, rest, symfony, laravel-4

I'm building a RESTful app with Laravel 4.2, using resource controllers, as described here:
https://scotch.io/tutorials/simple-laravel-crud-with-resource-controllers

The app is an online publishing platform.
One part of the app allows clients to upload images and crop the images for different publications. 
Each image may be tagged with title, artist, description.

Typically, the RESTful GET-index request URL would look like this.
HTTP GET: example.com/image/

Each image would be retrieved with a URL like this.
HTTP GET: example.com/image/{id}

Image number 3 would be deleted with HTTP DELETE to a URL like this.
HTTP DELETE: example.com/image/3

However my RESTful dilemma arises because each image must be stored in pre-defined crop sizes.
Thus an image resource will share title, artist and description, and will have representations that must be retrievable in four different sizes:
  Original,
  1024x768,
   640x480,
   320x240

The expected demand is about 80,000 images per year, resulting in 320,000 separate image files (Original + 3 crops each).

Here is where I'm looking for "best-practice" advice...

What should my Image Model look like to allow clients to address an end-point for easy retrieval of each cropped image?

What would be a good way of handling the common nature of title, artist and description?

What would the URLs look like if I wanted to retrieve Image #3 in Original and in 1024x768:
  Original: example.com/image/???
  1024x768: example.com/image/???

What would the URL look like if I wanted to DELETE all cropped versions of Image #3:
  HTTP DELETE: example.com/image/???

Thanks for any thoughts you can share!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would argue that the thumbnails are sub-resources of the `Image` resource; perhaps a `Thumbnail` resource? Therefore, you could have a URL structure something like the following:

- http://example.com/image/{id}
- http://example.com/image/{id}/thumbnail/{small|medium|large}

Nested resource controllers are achievable in Laravel: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/controllers#restful-resource-controllers (search for the heading “Handling Nested Resource Controllers”).

This way, you could manipulate individual thumbnail resources, but also images (and any thumbnails) by issuing requests the parent `Image` resource—just set up an listener on the `Image` model to delete child `Thumbnail` resources first when deleting an `Image` resource. Something like this:

```
Image::deleting(function($image)
{
    Thumbnail::where('image_id', '=', $image->id)->delete();
});
```

Comment: Thanks, Laravel's "Nested" Controller Routing is exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 7):

I don't know how Laravel works with Restful APIs, but in general the rules for urls in Restful APIs a little bit different.

- get single object - http://example.com/images/{id} - with method GET
- get list - http://example.com/images - with method GET
- insert/create a new object - http://example.com/images - with method POST
- DELETE - http://example.com/images/{id} - with method DELETE
- PUT - http://example.com/images/{id} - with method PUT
- get single object with some parameters - http://example.com/images/{id}?type=small - with method GET

Also I found [this](http://www.vinaysahni.com/best-practices-for-a-pragmatic-restful-api) article very usefull.

Comment: Agreed: Vinay Sahni article consolidates a lot of good information in one place.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Sized image files are subordinate resources to the original image resource.  So the size info should come after the id: http://example.com/image/3/1024x768 (or since your resolutions are static, you could do somethiing like http://example.com/image/3/large)

If you want to delete original and all sizes, DELETE http://example.com/image/3

If you want to delete a single size, DELETE http://example.com/image/3/1024x768

If you want to upload a new image size, you could do, POST http://example.com/image/3 (use code to check the image size)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what would be the "best" practice.

From my point of view it would be good practice to follow the OASIS Open Data Protocol (OData) Version 4.0

See http://www.odata.org/getting-started/basic-tutorial for more